# Ubuntu 16.04 installation RAID issue

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, raid, mdadm, alternate

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on a pc with two 2T HDs (no other OS).
My endpoint is to get Ubuntu installed on a partition set as RAID1, the swap set on a partition with RAID0, and a third partition for data storage set as RAID1 again.

I've created 3 partitions in each drive with GParted from live usb: sda1 (ext4), sda5 (swap) and sda6 (NTFS). Same configuration is set for sdb.

Now I would like to set sda1-sdb1 in RAID1 (as md0) where to install Ubuntu (this should be the booting point), `sda5-sdb5` in RAID0 (as md1) for the swap, `sda6-sdb6` in RAID1(as md2)  for data storage.
I've tried to set the three RAID volumes using mdadm from live cd (and it looked I manage to successfully create the md volumes), but when I try to install Ubuntu from the live usb, it does NOT find the md volumes but only the sd ones. How can I install it on the RAID drive?

I've tried to follow the instruction found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) and [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-raid.html), but I never found the RAID options during installation.

I've read there should be an Alternate CD with more advanced installations options, but is that still available for 16.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues trying to install ubuntu on a RAID 0 array in the past.

The default installer was just not working.

The way I finally managed to do it was to use the Ubuntu Server installer, which seems to read RAID arrays much better, and then install the `ubuntu-desktop` package on top of that to get the UI.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. For timing constraint, tough, I had to install the system anyway and start using it, but now is using only one HDD and the raid is not set. If I can re-install the system I will try your solution, otherwise I might try to move to raid after the system is set up, playing with mdadm.

Comment: I see. If you do try it and it does work, make sure you accept the answer :)